# TypeScript type coverage tool

Tags: typescript

Is there any tooling for type coverage in TypeScript world? Something like `flow coverage` report.

Examples for FlowType: https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-coverage-report

Answer (score 1):

[`type-coverage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-coverage) seems promising. Unfortunately, I can't test it in my current environment due to Node version incompatibility but it looks like exactly what I was looking for as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know it might be a bit late, but I just built and released `typescript-coverage-report` which is basically the TypeScript counterpart of the Flow tool and uses [type-coverage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-coverage) to collect data.

https://github.com/alexcanessa/typescript-coverage-report